# Instantiate inside nested for loops does not do what it is intended to

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, instantiation, minecraft

I have been working on  a minecraft clone game in Unity 2017.3 and C# and i started all right but when i worked on the super flat world generation system there began a problem. Inside the World mono behaviour, in the Generate void, there are three nested for loops which should generate a new dirt block on every possible position between 0 and 5

But it only makes a line of dirt block stretching along the Z axis.

Here is the code for PlaceableItem(attached to dirtPrefab) and World(attached to World)

**Placeable Item class**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlaceableItem : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string nameInInventory = "Unnamed Block";
    public int maxStack = 64;

    public bool destructible = true;
    public bool explodesOnX = false;
    public bool abidesGravity = false;
    public bool isContainer = false;
    public bool canBeSleptOn = false;
    public bool dropsSelf = false;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (abidesGravity) {
            rb.useGravity = true;
        } else {
            rb.useGravity = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (dropsSelf) {
            //Drop this gameObject
        }
    }

    public void Explode() {
        if (!explodesOnX)
            return;
    }

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (isContainer && !canBeSleptOn) {
            //Open the container inventory
        } else if (canBeSleptOn && !isContainer) {
            //Make the character sleep on the item
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseOver()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && destructible) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

**World class**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class World : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject dirtPrefab;

    public bool generateAutomatically = true; 

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if (generateAutomatically) {
            Generate();
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void Generate() {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y <= 5; y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z <= 5; z++) {
                    Instantiate(dirtPrefab, new Vector3(x, y, z), Quaternion.identity);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void RemoveAllBlocks() {
        foreach (PlaceableItem placeableItem in GetComponentsInChildren<PlaceableItem>()) {
            Destroy(placeableItem.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, fellow developers!
Hope this is not a stupid question!

Comment: You must format source code by indenting it four spaces. Otherwise it gets garbled by the markdown. You can block select and use the toolbar at the top of the question editor to format it. Ctrl+K indents selected text also.

Comment: Does it instantiate 125 gameobjects? Is it possible for u to provide a screenshot of the scene editor, of the blocks instantiated?

Comment: 216 actually (6*6*6)

Comment: How many objects do you see in the Inspector Window while debugging? See if you have 216 (since you have <= 5). If there are, see if some script / physics is changing it's position

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions in the debug console? If all of your loops are completing successfully this should work. Create a Debug.Log that logs all of the values of x,y, and z before instantiation.

Comment: Just so you're aware, you're embarking down a path that will ultimately not work. By having *each an every block* in your world instantiated as an object, even a tiny world (one Minecraft chunk) will consume hundreds of megabytes of RAM. Minecraft internally tracks the world as an array of *integers* which is what allows for huge detail on a low memory footprint.

Comment: Just to add to Draco's post, it's actually a multidimensional byte[] if I remember correctly... But still, I started on the same path as you until I learned about "chunks" and "octrees", etc. I think for most, this is a much needed learning experience although it ends in failure. I learned a TON about optimization from making this mistake.

Comment: @BrandonMiller Yes, you are correct. It was (a very complicated) fixed sized Byte array. Nominally broken down into 16x16x16 minichunks, 16 per chunk. 1.12 changed things, there's no longer the 4096 block limit (the internal storage is now string based, I think, I haven't looked).

Comment: @Draco18s That's pretty cool, actually. I'd like to know how they stringified all that data and actually put it to good use.... I foresee an absolute TON of regex in those developers' near future. Do you mean it's serialized into JSON and stored locally, or they're storing an actual string? Anyhow, the source code behind MC's world generation is fascinating.

Comment: @BrandonMiller Like I said, I haven't looked at how its handled in 1.12, I just know that the block limit is gone and that "thing are stored as strings." The lookup from string -> Block is handled via a Dictionary-type object. Its got some other interfaces and extensions applied, but it's just a fancy lookup table.

Comment: @BrandonMiller you and draco sound useful. But i just want to start off easy and not go into the details of RAM and hardware problems. But i am fine. Actually, my MacBook Pro 2015 can handle even a bigger chunk. So do not judge me. I will dig into that when i will not be as bad at unity.

Comment: @Makubex it seems there are 216 objects, but the World script appears to create a 1x1x6 box of dirt instead 6x6x6 box. What is even weirder is that there are 6 blocks on one Z position. And no, I removed the rigid body from the prefab and all code that could affect physics. What could, however, make things worse is that the dirt block prefab somehow has a rectTransform instead of Transform. Is this normal?

Comment: Andrew: something is indeed screwy. Your block definitely shouldn't have had a RectTransform on it (are you *sure* about that?), but I don't see what in the code you have posted, would account for it creating the blocks all in the same place. Normally that'd be due to something like `new Vector3(0,0,x)` or `new Vector3(x,x,x)`

Comment: @Andrew Please post a screenshot of your scene heirarchy, and a screenshot of the dirtPrefab and all the components on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] I realised i had a recttransform somehow attached to my dirt prefab. Removing it and adding a transform instead helped.